# Difference between VSTS git and Other Git provider

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have been using VSTS git for a while, it works fine for all common needs, but there are some subtle difference and I don't really understand the reason.
For example,

- in Github or bitbucket, the git repo url is normally append with
  '.git" extension, but VSTS is like '/_git/[name]'.
- Another thing is you can add hash at the end of Github/Bitbucket url
  like    'xxx.git#1.0.1', that is useful if you want to reference a
  version    from your npm package.json, but it does not work in that
  way at VSTS.

Can anyone help to explain these to me? and is there any other differences?

Thanks

Comment: The URL format is defined by each company separately. It's not make sence to require all the URL formats are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is usually:

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/{team project}
```

You can test it with a final ".git": it should not change anything.

For the tags, check the [section "view tags"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/06/14/view-tags-for-git-repositories/), and click on one ot check its URL.

[image: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/06/09-ContextMenu3.png]

The other differences are mainly around the [integration of Git and the work items](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/) (tickets specific to this ALM -- Application Lifecycle Manager)